# Apache: how to run PHP files via CGI as normal user and without them being executable

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd, cpanel, suexec

## Background

### Config of server I want to mimic

I have access to a CentOS 7 server with cPanel/WHM installed, running EasyApache4 with the following configuration:

```
# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf --current
DEFAULT PHP: ea-php56
ea-php55 SAPI: cgi
ea-php56 SAPI: cgi
ea-php70 SAPI: cgi
# rpm -qa|grep ruid2
# rpm -qa|grep suexec
ea-apache24-mod_suexec-2.4.33-5.5.1.cpanel.x86_64
```

I believe `suEXEC` is enabled, because `/var/log/apache2/error_log` contains entries like `AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)`.

I believe neither `mod_ruid2`, nor `suPHP`, nor `PHP-FPM`, nor `FastCGI`, nor `DSO` (aka `mod_php`) are enabled.

This server has a user, **myuser**, whose `~/public_html/public/` directory is used as the document root for the website **mywebsite.com**. (These are not the real names, obviously.)

If I put, in that directory, a PHP file called `whoami.php` with the following contents (note the lack of a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))):

```
<html>
<body>
<p>sapi_name:      <?php print php_sapi_name();    ?></p>
<p>exec whoami:    <?php print exec('whoami');     ?></p>
<p>system whoami:  <?php system('whoami');         ?></p>
<p>system id -a:   <?php system("id -a");          ?></p>
<p>getcurrentuser: <?php print get_current_user(); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and visit it in the browser at `http://mywebsite.com/whoami.php` (note that this is *not* using the `http://mywebsite.com/~myuser/whoami.php` UserDir URL format), it renders as:

> sapi_name: cgi-fcgi
>   exec whoami: myuser
>   system whoami: myuser
>   system id -a: uid=1002(myuser) gid=1003(myuser) groups=1003(myuser)
>   getcurrentuser: myuser

### Behaviour I want to mimic

This is true even if it lacks the executable permission, as follows:

```
$ ls -l /home/myuser/public_html/public/whoami.php | cut -d' ' -f1,3,4,9
-r-------- myuser myuser /home/myuser/public_html/public/whoami.php
```

Normally, Apache 2.4 in CGI mode cannot run a non-executable file like this, if I understand [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html) correctly:

> Of course, the file will have to exist, **and be executable**, and return output in a particular way, or Apache will return an error message.

However, cPanel/WHM seems to do *something* to alter this fact. According to the [WHM documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/PHP+Handlers):

> ### CGI
>
> The CGI handler executes PHP applications through the `mod_cgi` or
>   the `mod_cgid` Apache modules.  If you install the suEXEC module, the
>   system executes PHP applications as the user that owns the VirtualHost
>   that served the request. If you uninstall the suEXEC module, the
>   system executes PHP applications as the `nobody` system user. The system
>   provides `mod_cgi` and `mod_ruid2` by default.
>
> You can customize the CGI handler's settings in the PHP `.user.ini`
>   file. […]
>
> > #### Important:
> >
> > If you **enable** a per-user module, such as suEXEC or Ruid2, you can
> >     execute PHP scripts with permissions of `0400`. If you disable a
> >     per-user module, such as suEXEC or Ruid2, you can execute PHP scripts
> >     with permissions of `0444`.

I.e. even without suEXEC or Ruid2 enabled, EasyApache4 is somehow able to make Apache process non-executable PHP files as CGI scripts rather than just serving them as static files.

## Questions

I have a different CentOS 7 machine, not routable from the internet, and for development only. It does *not* have cPanel/WHM installed. Security is **not** a priority for this machine, and it has SELinux disabled. Mimicking cPanel/WHM's behaviour **is** a priority for this machine: top priority.

1. On this machine, how would I persuade Apache 2.4 to run PHP files whose permissions are `0400` or `0444`, and that lack a shebang, as CGI scripts via PHP 5.6, rather than just serving them as static files? I.e. how would I achieve the *something* alluded to above? I'm happy to compile Apache with non-standard [suEXEC configuration options](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/suexec.html#install), if needed.
2. In particular, how can I do this while serving them *without* needing use a UserDir URL (i.e. without the `/~myuser` part of a URL such as `http://mywebsite.com/~myuser/mypage.php`)?
3. How would I do all this while *also* ensuring that those files are run by **myuser**, via suEXEC, rather than by the **apache** or **httpd** or **nobody** user?

If you can answer all three questions at a stroke, so much the better, but even if you can answer just the first one, that would be very helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: I would advise not making so many questions at once. The thematic of PHP security is also a complicated theme too. ruid2 has also its own peculiarities, and I do not recommend it to unexperienced users.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, thanks. I have now clarified that the second machine is a development box, not routable from the Internet. Its purpose is to mimic the EasyApache4 box, not to be secure in itself. Also, AFAICT, the EasyApache4 box is not running Ruid2.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, as for not asking several questions at once, the motivation for my question is that I am not certain how to accomplish all of those things simultaneously. The different components are sufficiently tightly coupled that asking questions about just one or the other would eliminate important context and likely not yield a working solution. But if you have a better suggestion, I am open to it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, thanks for your good intentions, but IMO those links are off-topic. The first link is about using mod_ruid2 for security, but (a) AFAICT I shouldn't need to install mod_ruid2 in order to mimic the EA4 box because the latter doesn't appear to be using it, and (b) I don't need the dev box to be secure against malicious clients because I am its only client. The second and third links are about blocking or throttling unwanted clients by using modsecurity and/or mod-evasive, neither of which is relevant to my question or my use-case. Thanks again.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, thanks, but that link just compares different PHP handlers. It does not help to answer my question. I appreciate your desire to help, but I'm afraid that posting off-topic links is not helpful. It just creates clutter. I would be grateful if you could refrain from doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read it? It was not meant as such. Imo a possible answer to your problem is using fastcgi

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, how would using FastCGI help? My question is about using CGI, not FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this which is OK for a private dev environment that is only being used for that purpose, but should **never** be used on an internet-routable machine.

Execute these rather radical commands:

```
# chown myuser:myser /usr/bin
# chown myuser:myser /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

then:

```
# chmod 711 /home/myuser
# chmod 755 /home/myuser/public_html
#
```

Also, (re-)compile Apache to have suEXEC's `AP_DOC_ROOT="/"`, and (re-)install it.

Modify `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` along these lines:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
ServerAdmin root@localhost
#ServerName example.local
ServerName localhost    
User apache
Group apache
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/myuser/public_html/public"
  SuexecUserGroup myuser myuser
  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/myuser/public_html/public/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>
  <Directory "/home/myuser/public_html/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

and modify `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` roughly like so:

```
ScriptAlias /local-bin /usr/bin
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 php
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /local-bin/php-cgi
```

Finally, (re-)start Apache.

This is the best approach that I found prior to asking the question above. However, there are almost certainly better alternatives, and I would like to learn about them, hence my posting the question. (For instance, installing a `php-cgi` binary in the user's home directory should in principle be a viable and less drastic measure than modifying the ownership of the system binary and its directory.)

So, please feel free to upvote this answer if it helped you, or to comment constructively if it did not help you, but I will hold off marking it as "correct" for a while, in the hope that better answers emerge.